# WordPress 5.0 - publish page immediately without double-check

Tags: posts

I just installed WordPress 5.0 and I'm getting used to the new admin area for publishing posts and pages. I notice that when I press "Publish", I get a "Double-check your settings before publishing." message.

How can I disable that so I can just publish with one click, like WordPress 4.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to this. There is a checkbox at the bottom of the publish sidebar, that says something like "Always perform check before publishing". I unchecked it and that solved the issue.

Comment: Thank you! So simple, but not obvious.  I find the double-check feature annoying when developing a site.